# How to decrypt this message using reverse encryption?

Tags: java, arrays, encryption

I essentially want to reverse the encryption to decrypt the messgae. Can anyone help me as to creating the code to do this? Thanks!!

/**
 * Encrypt and Decrypt a String
 * @author (Andrew Gruber) 
 * @version (January 11th, 2016)
 */

public class logic

{

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //Encryption
    String mm= "where is the moose that everyone is talking about";
    final int nr=6; //number or rows
    int nc; //number of columns

    nc=mm.length()/nr;
    if(mm.length()% nr !=0){
        nc++;
    }

    while(mm.length()<nr*nc){ //insert spaces 
        mm+=" ";
    }

    String[][] ar=new String [nr][nc];

    for(int i=0; i<mm.length(); i++){
        //eaach character in the string is stored
        ar[i%nr][i/nr]=mm.substring(i,i+1);

    }

    String outStr=""; //output string
    for(int r=0; r<nr; r++){
        for(int c=0; c<nc; c++){
            outStr+=ar[r][c];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(outStr);
    //Decryption

    String test=outStr;
    Decyrption();


}
static void Decyrption(){
```

Comment: By "help you" im assuming you are meaning "us do it for you"?

Comment: well all i really need is an idea of how to put it back into the array and assort it back into the string accordingly. I know what to do but i just need some help coding it. no im not asking for you to do all of it. Surely that will help but i wont learn the best that way. Thanks! +redFive

Answer (score 0):

This is a transposition cipher, akin to [transposition of a matrix.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) You write the message in a grid, then swap rows and columns, so that instead of an r x c grid, you have a c x r grid.

```
                  |wt rtb|
|where is |       |hhtyao|
|the moose|       |eeholu|
| that eve|  -->  |r ankt| --> "wt rtbhhtyaoeeholur anktemtei  o  n ioeig ssvs   ee a "
|ryone is |       |emtei |
|talking a|       | o  n |
|bout     |       |ioeig |
                  |ssvs  |
                  | ee a |
```

You can see that if you transpose again, you will get back the original grid, effectively decrypting the message.

You already have the code for filling a grid, transposing it, and creating a string from its contents. Just invoke it again with the correct grid dimensions. Rather than cut'n'paste all that code, try to create another function that contains the code, and call that function twice from your `main` function, with different parameters.